# KMM library and context

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am doing kmm library.

I would like to be able to have something like that:

In commonMain

```
expect class UploadManager() {
    fun execute()
}
```

In androidMain:

```
actual class UploadManager() {
    fun execute(){
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(WorkRequestManager().getWorkRequest())
    }
}
```

How can I get context in android part of shared module?

Comment: do you mean the context of shared module or just android context ?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to this party, but Android context can't be accessed in the Shared module because it's a business library.
It will cause a circular dependency, then on top of that it won't work for iOS.

What you can do is to expose the Android context inside the source set.
You can use this jetpack library to pass the Application Context generated on Startup by registering the component on your manifest.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/startup

Once you open the app, the OS will pass the context of the Application being opened up, and it will pass the Application context into the registered source set.

You can then access the context from there.